# Unable to save with two models id field

Tags: django-rest-framework

Groom can like Bride, and Bride can like Groom. These two are different models in Likes Model.
I'm using the view set. Able to save individual model data but when I save Likes DRF throws field required error. Please suggest how to do better handling of many to many relationship handling between two models.

I also tried with ForeignKey relation in the models. The from bride/groom would be enforced with logged-in user id that is register bride/groom id (pk).

**Models**

```
class RegisterBride(models.Model):
'''Register Bride/Female profiles.'''
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Female')
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, validators=[                                      MinValueValidator(18), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    bride_account_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname + ' '+self.lname


class RegisterGroom(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Male')
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, validators=[                                      MinValueValidator(18), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    groom_account_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname + ' '+self.lname


class Likes(models.Model):
    bride_profile = models.ManyToManyField(RegisterBride, related_name='bride_profile')
    groom_profile = models.ManyToManyField(RegisterGroom, related_name='groom_profile')
    likes = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Views**

```
class RegisterGroomProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RegisterGroom.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegisterGroomSerializer


class RegisterBrideProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RegisterBride.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegisterBrideSerializer


class LikesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Likes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikesSerializer
```

**Serializers**

```
class RegisterGroomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = RegisterGroom
    fields = '__all__'


class RegisterBrideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RegisterBride
        fields = '__all__'


class LikesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groom_profile_s = RegisterGroomSerializer(many=True, required=True)
    bride_profile_s = RegisterBrideSerializer(many=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Likes
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'likes': {'required': True}}

    def create(self, data):
        if data['bride_profile'] == data['groom_profile']:
            raise ValidationError(detail='To Profile ID == From Profile ID. They should be different.')
        return data
```

**Request**

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/likes/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request

{'likes': True,
'bride_profile': 1,
'groom_profile': 6}
```

**Response**

```
POST /likes/
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "groom_profile_s": [
        "This field is required."
   ],
    "bride_profile_s": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

**Server Error:**

```
..\rest_framework\pagination.py:200: UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'register.models.Likes'> QuerySet.
```

paginator = self.django_paginator_class(queryset, page_size)

Please suggest me.

Comment: Just a question, why you wanna use a single `Likes` model ? looks like confusing for me; you cannot know who liked who. I'd go to two models `BrideLikes` and `GroomLikes`

Comment: I want to enforce the from to logged user id.
I didn't think about two separate models. This is a nice idea. So if there are two models for Likes how to relate them with respective Bride/Groom models?

Comment: at model lever they could be exactly the same (same fields of `Likes` model). Anyway honestly I think your problem is in the `LikesSerializer`: by default a viewset serializer shouls serialize a single record of the model

Comment: Thank you @MassimoCosta! Any thoughts how to resolve and what is the problem. Sorry I'm new and still learning.

Comment: What is the POST request you are sending ?

Comment: Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/likes/
Request Method: POST

likes: true
bride_profile: 1
groom_profile: 6

like: True/False.bride/groom profile = id values.

Comment: @Henri updated the Question summary also with Request data at the bottom.

Comment: In the LikesSerializer you use `many=True` this means that the serializer expects lists

Comment: Yes, it's one-to-many relationship that I want to develop.

Comment: One more thing I just observed in the Browsable API client. The Raw Data Content shwos, duplicate entries for request pay load.

Payload:
{
    "groom_profile_s": [],
    "bride_profile_s": [],
    "likes": false,
    "bride_profile": null,
    "groom_profile": null
}

And the Servers throws:
..\rest_framework\pagination.py:200: UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'register.models.Likes'> QuerySet.
  paginator = self.django_paginator_class(queryset, page_size)

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not good : you put `groom_profile_s` and `bride_profile_s` as required but you do not send them in your request !

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/likes/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request

{'likes': True,
'groom_profile_s': [1],
'bride_profile_s': [6]}
```

After modifying your query, you should update your serializer.

```
class LikesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groom_profile_s = RegisterGroomSerializer(many=True, required=True)
    bride_profile_s = RegisterBrideSerializer(many=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Likes
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'likes': {'required': True}}

    def create(self, data):
        if 'groom_profile_s' in data.keys():
            groom_profile_s = validated_data.pop('groom_profile_s')
            // Deal with your data here by creating the Like
        // Same for bride_profile_s
```

Comment: I'm not able to send the request, the browsable page hangs or not allowed to send. One basic q'n is my Model and Serializes design correct?